# Declaring property of interface type inside another interface

Tags: c#

I have a interface called ITaskManager which contains signatures of methods as follows,

```
public interface ITaskManager
{
   void Initialize();
   void CloseConnection();
   void OpenConnection()
}
```

And one more interface ITaskScheduler,

```
public interface ITaskScheduler
{
   void Schedule();
   ITaskManager Task { get; }

}
```

So what is the benefit of **ITaskManager Task { get; }** declaration ?

Comment: A Proper **Abstraction**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will provide abstraction.
Later on you can have various task manager inheriting from `ITaskManager` lets say `DataBaseTaskManager`, `FileTaskManager`.

This way you can work at interface level without worrying about the concrete implemetation of the `ITaskManager` and `ITaskScheduler`.

Comment: I know interface helps to achieve generalization, but what is the point of "ITaskManager Task { get; }" declaration ?

Comment: With `ITaskManager Task { get; }` you can get the instance of `TaskManager` handling the particular `ITaskScheduler`.
And it is definitely based on the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one ITaskManager and the Task Scheduler needs an ITaskManager in order to live.

Heres a better example:

```
public interface IResturant
{
   IMenu Menu {get;}
}

public interface IMenu
{
   Dictionary<string,double> MenuItems{get;}
}

public class BurgerKingMenu : IMenu
{
   // Menu items will contain the whole Burger King menu
}

public class KFCMenu : IMenu
{
   // Menu items will contain the whole KFC menu
}

public class KFCResturant : IResturant
{
   // will get KFC's IMenu
}

public class BurgerKingReturant : IResturant
{
   // will get Burger King's IMenu
}
```